# Filter by exact date after receiving webapp2 request on Python GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

After receiving the the date by `q = self.request.get('q')`, I am trying to filter by complete date, but it gives me blank results. My query is as follows:

```
custQuery = db.Query(Customer)
birthdate = datetime.strptime(q,"%Y-%m-%d")
custQuery.filter('birthdate >= ',birthdate)
custQuery.filter('birthdate < ',birthdate)
```

But, I get blank results although I know that the q(which is the certain date) is existing and I have an existing `birthdate` property. What is the proper way to filter requests by exact date on Google App Engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me. It should be equal sign.

```
custQuery = db.Query(Customer)
birthdate = datetime.strptime(q,"%Y-%m-%d").date()
custQuery.filter('birthdate = ',birthdate)
```